# Finding automorphism group of $\langle a,b\mid a^5=b^{11}=1,\ aba^{-1}=b^3\rangle.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group, group-presentation

Consider the group

$$G = \langle a,b\mid a^5=b^{11}=1,\ aba^{-1}=b^3\rangle.$$

I wish to understand $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$, the automorphism group of this presentation. I could not find a systematic way to solve this. Using Magma, I found that this should be a group of order $110$; specifically, it is the group generated by the two maps $\phi^1$ and $\phi^2$, where these are given by $\phi^1(a) = a$, $\phi^1(b) = b^6$ and $\phi^2(a) = ab$, $\phi^2(b) = b$ respectively. Hence I believe the group to be $\mathbb{Z}_2 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_{55}$ but how can this be found.

Comment: $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\cong \mathrm{AGL}(1,10)\cong C_{11}\rtimes C_{10}$ (but it is not isomorphic to $C_2\rtimes C_{55}$).

Comment: Just for the record, this is a special case of Example 1 of the paper by M. J. Curran: [Automorphisms of semidirect products. Math. Proc. R. Ir. Acad. 108 (2008), no. 2, 205-210](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40656982).

Comment: @verret why is it not isomorphic to $C_2 \rtimes C_{55}$ aswell.

Comment: Well, for example, a normal $C_2$ has to be central, so a group of the form $C_2\rtimes X$ in fact is $C_2\times X$. Also, the group does not contain a $C_{55}$ subgroup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**My solution:** ${\rm Aut}(G)\cong \Bbb Z/11\Bbb Z \rtimes \Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z$.

**Start by studying the group $G$:**
Since $aba^{-1}=b^3$, then also $a^{-1}ba=b^4$ and so every element in $G$ has the form $a^hb^k$ for $0\le h\le 4$ and $0\le k\le 10$. In particular, $G$ is a non abelian group of order $55$ and thus it is $$G\cong \Bbb Z/11\Bbb Z\rtimes \Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z.$$
$G$ has only one $11$-Sylow, given by $\langle b\rangle$ and all the other elements have order $1$ or $5$.

**Calculating the order of ${\rm Aut}(G)$:**
Let $\phi\in{\rm Aut}(G)$, because of order reasons $\phi(a)=a^nb^m$ and $\phi(b)= b^k$ for such $1\le n\le 4$, $0\le m\le 10$ and $1\le k\le 10$.
Imposing the condition $\phi(aba^{-1})=\phi(b^3)$, we obtain the condition $a^nb^ka^{-n}=b^{3k}$, that becomes $b^{3^nk}=b^{3k}$, i.e. $n= 1 \mod 5$ and then $n=1$.
So $\phi(a)=ab^m$ and $\phi(b)=b^k$ for $0\le m\le 10$ and $1\le k\le 10$.
We conclude that $|{\rm Aut}(G)|=11\cdot 10=110$.

**Studying the structure of ${\rm Aut}(G)$:**
Since ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is a group of order $2\cdot 5\cdot 11$ you can conclude suddenly that there exists a normal subgroup of order $55$ (search for “$pqr$-groups”) and then thanks to Cauchy’s Theorem ${\rm Aut}(G)\cong (\Bbb Z/11\Bbb Z\rtimes \Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z) \rtimes \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z $.

Another way, with some counts, is the following.

The $j$-th iteration of $\phi$ gives $\phi^j(b)=b^{k^j}$ and then if we want an automorphism of order multiple of $10$ we can ask that the multiplicative order of $k\mod 11$ is $10$, for example we can choose $k=2$.
So, we fix the automorphism $\Phi(a)=a$ and $\Phi(b)=b^2$.
Similarly, we search for an automorphism of order multiple of $11$: this time we may ask $k=m=1$ and we see that $\phi^j(a)=ab^j$, that in fact has order $11$.
So, we fix the automorphism $\Psi(a)=ab$ and $\Psi(b)=b$.
We finally observe that $\Phi\circ\Psi\circ \Phi^{-1}=\Psi^2$ and so ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is a non abelian group of order $110$, product of $\langle \Psi\rangle$ and $\langle\Phi\rangle$ with the right orders and such that the second subgroup stays in the normalizator of the first.
We conclude that $${\rm Aut}(G)= \langle \Psi\rangle\rtimes\langle\Phi\rangle\cong \Bbb Z/11\Bbb Z \rtimes \Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z.$$

Comment: I think the section when you calculate the order of $Aut(G)$ only shows an upper bound of 110 for the order, one would still have to check that all these possibilities correspond to actual automorphisms.

Comment: I don't see why $a^{-1}ba=b^4$.

Comment: We have $a^{-1}b^3a=b$ so just raising it to the power of $4$ gives $a^{-1}ba=b^4$ due to the fact that $b^{12} =b$.

Comment: The only thing left to do in this solution is show that $\phi(a)^5 = 1$ but this works because the sums of the powers of 4 upto the 4th power is divisible by 11, hence the order is exactly 110. A final comment for future reference is that not all groups of order 55 are $\mathbb{Z}_{55}$. Otherwise this a great answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Comment: @verret, yes you are right: when I realized that, I thought that actually the last part shows also that the automorphism group has at least $110$ elements, but I agree with you that the answer could be clearer

Comment: @2253037o the fact that $\phi(a)^5=1$ follows from the fact that the unique elements of order 11 are the powers of $b$ and that the group is not abelian (thus not cyclic this time). I corrected the fact that the subgroup of order $55$ is not cyclic, thank you!